# How to disable the Naming convention alerts in Visual Studio Community OS X?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

How to disable the Naming convention alerts in Visual Studio Community OS X?

[image]

Comment: No responses, hmm. Must have made folks bend their necks too much.. - Seriously, I know there are options in the main menu but I tend to click on the errors pane to make them go away.